# Materialize css 'Card reveal' not working on my page

Tags: html, materialize

I have a table populated inside a card but due to some reason card reveal is not showing up.

What could be the reason. Mentioned below is my html codes:

```
<div class="container container-90 content-section" style="vertical-align: middle">
    <div class="row center"></div>
    <div class="card">
    <div class="card-content">
    
    <div class="tbl-header">
    <table class="striped" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="mytable" >
    <thead>
    
    <tr>
    <th bgcolor="#f5f5f5" style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center"><label><input type="checkbox" class="filled-in" id='s1c' onchange="toggletask('s1-');"/><span style="color:#757575">Check All</span></label></th>
    <th bgcolor="#f5f5f5"  style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center">Date</th>
    <th bgcolor="#f5f5f5"  style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center">Agent</th>
    <th bgcolor="#f5f5f5"  style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center">Current Compoffs</th>
    <th bgcolor="#f5f5f5"  style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center">Number of Compoffs</th>
    </tr>
    
    </thead>
    
    </table>

    <div class="tbl-content">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="custom-table">
    <tbody id="perf">
    
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="row center">
    <button id='btnRoster' class="waves-effect waves-light btn blue-grey darken-3">Submit</button>
    </div>
    </div>
   
    </div>
    <div class="card-reveal">
      <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">close</i></span>
      <p>Here is some more information about this product that is only revealed once clicked on.</p>
    </div>
    </div>
```

I want an option to appear like this where card reveal could work as shown in materialize site:-

[image]

Comment: Your problem is not clear. Please give more details.

Comment: can you see the three dots in the image I just added. when we click on it a new overlay appears. I want the same to be done on my card. but the dots are not appearing.

Answer (score 0):

There are two DIVs not closed, one DIV instant closed, no Style and a lot of code we need to held you.

This should work:

```
    <div class="container container-90 content-section" style="vertical-align: middle">
  <div class="row center">  
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-content">        
          <span class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">more_vert</i></span>
          <p>
            <a href="#">This is a link</a>
          </p>
        </div>
         <div class="col s12" style="height: 100px"> 
          <div class="card-reveal">
            <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">close</i></span>
              <p>Here is some more information about this product that is only revealed once clicked on.</p>
          </div>
         </div>      
        <div class="tbl-header">
      <table class="striped" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="mytable">
        <thead>      
          <tr>
          <th bgcolor="#f5f5f5" style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center"><label><input type="checkbox" class="filled-in" id='s1c' onchange="toggletask('s1-');"/><span style="color:#757575">Check All</span></label></th>
          <th bgcolor="#f5f5f5"  style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center">Date</th>
          <th bgcolor="#f5f5f5"  style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center">Agent</th>
          <th bgcolor="#f5f5f5"  style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center">Current Compoffs</th>
          <th bgcolor="#f5f5f5"  style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center">Number of Compoffs</th>
          </tr>      
        </thead>      
      </table>  
      <div class="tbl-content">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="custom-table">
          <tbody id="perf">
        
      
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
        <div class="row"><br><br>     
          <div class="row center">
            <button id='btnRoster' class="waves-effect waves-light btn blue-grey darken-3">Submit</button>        
          </div>     
        </div>     
      </div>     
   </div> 
  </div> 
</div>
```

Code at the bottom:

```
<div class="container container-90 content-section" style="vertical-align: middle">
  <div class="row center">  
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-content">        
         
        <div class="tbl-header">
      <table class="striped" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="mytable">
        <thead>      
          <tr>
          <th bgcolor="#f5f5f5" style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center"><label><input type="checkbox" class="filled-in" id='s1c' onchange="toggletask('s1-');"/><span style="color:#757575">Check All</span></label></th>
          <th bgcolor="#f5f5f5"  style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center">Date</th>
          <th bgcolor="#f5f5f5"  style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center">Agent</th>
          <th bgcolor="#f5f5f5"  style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center">Current Compoffs</th>
          <th bgcolor="#f5f5f5"  style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center">Number of Compoffs</th>
          </tr>      
        </thead>      
      </table>  
      <div class="tbl-content">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="custom-table">
          <tbody id="perf">
        
      
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
        <div class="row"><br><br>     
          <div class="row center">
            <button id='btnRoster' class="waves-effect waves-light btn blue-grey darken-3">Submit</button>        
          </div>  
          <span class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">more_vert</i></span>
          <p>
            <a href="#">This is a link</a>
          </p>
        </div>
         <div class="col s12" style="height: 100px"> 
          <div class="card-reveal">
            <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">close</i></span>
              <p>Here is some more information about this product that is only revealed once clicked on.</p>
          </div>
         </div>         
        </div>     
      </div>     
   </div> 
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm... It works for me. Try it in a New DOM for testing.

Comment: ok but the three dots are appearing at the top but it should appear at the bottom. so that it could reveal. The table is actually card content.

Comment: move the code to the bottom. i edit my code awnser. stop working with table, use grid or flex box. use helpful pattern, stop waste time antipattern. you are more abl eto see mistakes.

Use visibilty to appear the dots.